# Exporting from SFDC to custom fixed-width type file

Tags: integration, data-export

For phase one of this integration project, the requirment is to export data to a fixed-width fields type flat file and place it in a specific folder on the network, where the legacy system with pick it up.

I was thinking of using and automated Dataloader job via a batch file, but I don't see how it can produce the file we need. Perhaps more research is needed :)

If this is not possible, would the next best approach be to create our own program in C# or other and use the SF API to  do what we want?

Any other options?

Thank  you.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, the Apex Dataloader only exports to CSV, so you would need to turn to a third-party.

Off of the top of my head, I know the Jitterbit Dataloader provides the functionality to export to both fixed width and character delimited file formats. You can grab it off of the AppExchange, or find more information here:

http://www.jitterbit.com/solutions/salesforce-integration/salesforce-data-loader/

Comment: Thank you Mark.

I will take a look at that option and see if it meets my requirements.

Comment: For others benefit, I checked out Jitterbit andd it looks like a great product. I installed and tried it and it's very easy to use and quite flexible.

Unfortunately, the cost is quite prohibitive. Their subscription starts at $1000/month for connections of up to 2 applications!

Comment: The Jitterbit Data Loader has a free version that should cover the requirements you outlined.